# What's different between two formulas in my problem. Which one shall I use.?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, waves

Lights waves are electromagnetic waves which moves with the speed of $c=3,0\times 10^8\text{m/s}$. The waves can be described using the formula $f(t)=A\sin (Bt)$. For yellow light with the estimated wavelength of $580$nm, I want to find the value of $B$.

> I tried use the following way: That $f(t)=A\sin(\omega t)$ where $\omega=2\pi f$, so $B=2\pi\dfrac{c}{\lambda}$. For yellow light I get $B=3.25\cdot 10^{15} s^{-1}$.

After, I saw a formula for a wave, that is $y(x,t)=A\sin\left(\dfrac{2\pi}{\lambda}x\pm\omega t\right)$.

My Questions are

> **(1)** Is my solution for $B=3.25\cdot 10^{15} s^{-1}$ true?
>
> **(2)** What's different between two formulas. Can I apply $y(x,t)=A\sin\left(\dfrac{2\pi}{\lambda}x\pm\omega t\right)$.?

Thanks.

Comment: When there is no $x$ term in the $\sin$ argument this is just a special case of the more general situation. The $x$ term describes a phase shift (depending on position in space) for the time oscillation; for example when we set $x=0$ we describe the oscillation of the field at the origin. (Just as for a wave travelling in water, different points are oscillating with the same frequency, but not in sync.) The $\omega$ appearing in the general case or the specific case is the same, as all points in space are oscillating with the same frequency, so it does not matter which formula you use.

Comment: I would advise learning more about the mathematical description of travelling waves (electromagnetic or otherwise, as the mathematics is essentially the same), as then questions such as this will be clear. Additionally, note that there is not really one function $f$ or $y$ that describes the electromagnetic wave; really there are two - the electric field $\vec{E}$ and the magnetic field $\vec{B}$ - but for a plane wave the two fields are highly correlated and in particular both have this same sinusoidal time dependence.

Comment: @diracula Thank. If I give you this problem, which formula do you suggest.

Comment: Both formulae are correct, but one is a special case of the other. It does not matter which one you use for your question. You might want to take a look at the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_wave) on plane waves, specifically the first part under 'mathematical formalisms'. (Also, in my previous comment, I should really have said that there are six functions describing the electromagnetic field, or two vector functions.)

Answer (score 1):

2(pi)/ lambda × x is phase difference between the two waves

Phase difference is the difference of wave phase between two waves

It used to show difference in wave phase of two waves of same frequency
It is comparison between two waves

So for one wave only when there is no comparison we give Equation as y = Asin(wt) and if equation is specified in question we use equation given in Question

In this question general wave is given therefore we will use equation you = Asin(wt)

So value of B you calculated is correct